# problemas al convertir .py a .exe con archivos .json

Tags: python, api

Problema al convertir mi archivo . py a .exe  el error:

```
Last login: Tue May 23 11:44:51 on ttys000
/Users/Emily/Desktop/ing ; exit;
iMac-de-Marco:~ Emily$ /Users/Emily/Desktop/ing ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ing.py", line 982, in <module>
  File "ing.py", line 72, in main
  File "ing.py", line 67, in load_config
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'formacero-laser-b59d374984c8.json'
[36356] Failed to execute script 'ing' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'formacero-laser-b59d374984c8.json'
[36356] Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ing.py", line 982, in <module>
  File "ing.py", line 72, in main
  File "ing.py", line 67, in load_config
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'formacero-laser-b59d374984c8.json'

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Proceso completado]
```

Pero el archivo si se encuentra en la misma carpeta del script y agrege el archivo:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "/Users/Emily/Desktop/programa/logo.ico" --add-data `
```